# Max supported speed for RAM for toshiba satellite a665-s6070?

Tags: laptop, memory

I cant find a reliable source that explains what is the maximum:

- Ram size
- Ram speed

That my `toshiba satellite a665-s6070` supports.

Currently I put 1 `8 GB 1600 mhz` + `4 GB 1600mhz` and it starts but the computer is shuting down automatically sometimes.

I tried with ubuntu memtest86 and it shutdowns there too, I tried removing each one and the same happen for both of the rams I have.

I also tried with 1 `2GB 1600 Mhz` and got same result.

Any recomendation?
What happens if I put a more faster RAM than the supported velocity for the computer?

Answer (score 3):

According to the page
[Crucial Toshiba Satellite A665-S6070 compatible upgrades](http://www.crucial.com/usa/en/compatible-upgrade-for/Toshiba/satellite-a665-s6070),
the maximum possible for your computer is 8 GB in two sticks of 4 GB:

[image]

Please note all the characteristics of the proposed memory, since you will need
to duplicate them almost exactly.
Crucial itself apparently does not sell this memory any more.

Note also that the
[manual](https://support.toshiba.com/support/modelHome?freeText=2681445)
for your computer specifies that when only one stick is installed,
it should be placed in the bottom slot A, as follows:

[image]

Comment: +1 for the crucial site. You can also do a similar RAMcheck on the Kingston site. Also, occasionally flashing the bios can allow more RAM.

Comment: So it should support a 1600 Mhz ram?

Comment: Yes, but this is not the only criteria.Pay attention also to DDR3 PC3-12800, CL=11, Unbuffered, NON-ECC, DDR3-1600, 1.35V.